# difficulties with basic file i/o in python script called from php

Tags: php, python

Like the file says I am executing a python script from a PHP file sitting on my apache webserver.  The example I have is extremely basic.

PHP file -- test.php

```
<?php
echo "hello";
echo exec("/usr/local/bin/python2.7 test1.py");
?>
```

python script -- test1.py

```
print "world"
fh = open ('testtest' ,'r')
for line in fh:
    print line
```

contents of -- testtest

```
abcdefg
```

'world' prints when I don't have the bottom 2 lines of `test1.py` but it stops printing as soon as I add `for line in file:`  Thank you. 
Edit:  I'm trying to print the contents of `testtest`.

Comment: There's an error in your code on the third line of `test.php`, you forgot to close parenthesis.

Comment: What happens if you run the python script directly?

Comment: Can you check your apache logs? Python could be raising an `AttributeError` if open returns `None`. Also, `'r'` is implied by `open`, so you can just do `for line in open('testtest'):`, or even better, make use of the `with` keyword.

Comment: @brainstorm the syntax error was my fault.  That parenthesis isn't missing in my php file (I just checked).

Comment: @Jack M. the  output of this when I open the php page in a browser is `hello`

Comment: What is the output of executing just the python script?  You should probably debug the python before you embed it into the php.

Comment: The output of the python script is correct `world abcdefg` (with a new line character I'm not sure how to do that in stackoverflow)

Comment: @stefan I just grep'd my apache logs for an Attribute error and there was none.  Only 2 instances of `python` at all and they weren't errors.

Comment: Change the line to read like:  `exec("/usr/local/bin/python2.7 test1.py 2>&1")` and see if it gives you more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exec does not do what you expect it to do. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) states that it only returns the last line of output. It recommends use of [passthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give you the green check once I try it out but this makes a lot of sense now....

Comment: passthru worked.  It should be noted, if you want to read from a file you must have +x on that file.  I had to chmod 777 testtest as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to assign to the variable `file`.  That's a built-in in Python.  You should use something like `fh` for file handle, or `inFile`, or the like.  That might be enough to address it.

Comment: @Rell3oT - Sure thing.  And you said you'd tried absolute paths to the file in question?  If you import sys and print sys.path what does it come up with?  Does it contain the directory where your script resides?  If not, `sys.path.append()` would let you specify it.

Comment: Python built-ins are just references, assigning to them never does anything bad, especially because it only affects the local scope, never modules. It's not necessarily _good_ practice, but never really bad.

Comment: Wow, i definitely wasn't expecting sys.path to be a list.  Yeah, `sys.path` contains the directory where `testtest` `test.php` and `test1.py` reside.